# What means "Association end could be owned either by end classifier, or association itself"?

Tags: oop, uml, associations

The above statement is taken from [www.uml-diagrams.org](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#association-end:%7E:text=or%20an%20editor.-,Association%20end%20could%20be%20owned%20either%20by,association%20itself,-Association%20ends%20of) section *Assocation ends* from the rather beginning.

- Is there a real-world example for this?
- What exactly means **owned by association itself**?
- What is association class or how is it implement in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt. I also was unsure about the nature of an association in the past and until not so long ago where I sort of grasped it. For the full pain you have to go through pp. 197 of UML 2.5 (**11.5 Associations**)

**What is an association?**

When you have a number of classes (we may call them `A`, `B`, etc. here for brevity. They are designed to be somewhat self-consistent. So you have properties and operations which work with the latter. If our `A` is some mathematical class you may have a well working black box. Fine.

Now, when any class is in need of another (e.g. the `B` class needs objects of type `A` to have that math toolbox handy) you create some reference. In a programming language that will be some variable holding a reference to an instance of the needed class. That's the moment where you have an association.

In UML you can denote such an association as a property typed with the other class. Or (!) you draw a line for an association between both class boxes and place the role name towards the referenced class (telling the name of the variable the programmer shall use). This being quite simple got me some headaches since I saw notations with both property and role notation. I have not fosteres the UML spec as tho what this would mean, but I established a rule I was also teaching that this is not allowed. Tools like EA do not support roles in a correct way which forces you to manually maintain your diagrams. That is, if you have an association role from `B` to `A` and the diagram does not contain `A` then you should show the role as property (see my note about dot notation below). But once you place `A` on that diagram you should see the assocation line with the role name, but not the property (pretty confusing I admit).

*Note*: **Dot notation**

Since UML 2.5 (or was it 2.1?; but see p. 200 of UML 2.5) the OMG guys introduced the so called dot notation. That is, you have a little dot at the association line end along where the role name is. This dot indicates that the role name is actually the property of the referencing class. Pretty much what I was talking about above. And what I thought was the intention. So, I have no idea what a not-owned property would be in any case. May be a good question to be asked.

**Associaton class**

Assume you have class `C` which reflects some kind of relation between `A` and `B` (and eventually `D`, `E`, etc.). Doing that makes it an association class. It's doing that by exactly the same technique as above, just for multiple classes. (If a class has multiple relations to other classes it's not necessarily an association class, but only if it's main purpose is to set these into some relation. YMMV)

So here you have the case where an association owns the role since you have a real object. The association explained above exists only as a reference in the programming world, not a complex storage structure like an association class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this your useful answer . I appreciate it that you consumed your time to answer my question .

Comment: I read your answer a few times and some of my questions that were in the dark part of my brain became clear. But I still don't fully understand what **owned by association itself** exactly means.

Comment: The UML-diagrams website I mentioned above says that **the ends of the association must belong to the _association itself_ , when the association has more than two ends**. I think ownership by the association happens when we have a association class. Is that right ?

Comment: Well, it's only if you have an association class. That has the ability to actually own a property. I confess that I walked ignorant for many years regarding assocation/classes. Probably the OMG guys are just a bunch of blockheads that lost contact to real people (I'm sarcastic as always). So their publication (the UML editions) are improving but for a technical document they are awful. They better start reading "Zen and the art of motorcycle maintenance".

Comment: Oh, cross post ;-) Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should understand that, as opposed to the explanation of @qwerty_so, in data/information modeling, ***relations*** between two objects (called "links" in UML) are a ***first-class citizen***. Logically/conceptually, they exist next to objects. In terms of OO implementation, they may exist either within one or both of the two participating objects in the form of object references, or outside of the two participating objects in the form of another object representing the "link".

Likewise, in data/information modeling, an Assocation, which classifies "links", is a first-class citizen that logically/conceptually exists next to the involved Classes. A binary Assocation is implementated either within one or both of the two (Java/C#/JS/etc.) classes involved in the form of a reference property (or possibly two mutually inverse reference properties), or outside of the two classes in the form of another class representing the Assocation.

In the case where a binary association has one ownership dot at one of its ends, it is *unidirectional* and implemented as a reference property in the corresponding class, while in the case where it has ownership dots at both of its ends, it is *bidirectional* and implemented as two *mutually inverse* reference properties, one in each of the involved classes.

> What exactly means owned by association itself?

An Assocation End of a binary Assocation can be owned either by the Class on the opposite side or by the Assocation itself. In the former (more common) case, the Assocation End corresponds to a reference property of the (Java/C#/JS/etc.) class on the opposite side. In the former (less common) case, the Assocation End corresponds to a reference property of the (Java/C#/JS/etc.) class that represents the Assocation.

In principle, there could be an OOP language that supports Assocations as first-class citizens, having a keyword "assocation", in addition to "class".

> What is association class or how is it implement in code?

The need for an Association Class arises when the "links" of an Association have to be characterized with the help of attributes, or when they have to be processed with the help of special operations. In such a case, an Association Class allows defining these attributes or operations. An Association Class is implemented in the form of a (Java/C#/JS/etc.) class that has corresponding reference properties for each of the Association's ends.

Comment: Thanks for this detail answer. There is some question __\n (in here pressing space is not possible :) ). 1_without using any association class , the association will be a semantic association ? and  2_This phrase "either within one or both of the two participating objects in the form of object references" mentions to navigability ?

Comment: @Wylie (1) What do you mean with "semantic association", do you refer to the case where an association is not explicitly represented as a special class? (2) Yes, in the case where a binary association has one ownership dot at one of its ends, it is "unidirectional" and implemented as a reference property in the corresponding class, while in the case where it has  ownership dots at both of its ends, it is "bidirectional" and implemented as two mutually inverse reference properties, one in each of the involved classes. See also my online book https://web-engineering.info/book/WebApp2/

Comment: (1) _ sorry I typed it wrong , yes I mean that "when there is not any specified association class , it will be a **semantic relationship** (it's impossible implementing in code and it just possible showing in UML)" ? or In other words , when we choose a name for association (it could be an association class) but when there is not any association class , it just a useless name in code and we can only showing that in UML. I hope I said what I meant

Comment: Yes, the name of an association does not show up in the code when it is not implemented as a separate class. In that case, only the names of the association ends with ownership dots show up as the names of corresponding reference properties.